# Problem with token authentcation filter in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I'm using Spring Boot 3, Java 17 and Maven 3.9 for an application. I'm creating a JWT token authentication for users, but the configure filter function is returning the following errors:

"The type javax.servlet.Filter cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity"

and

"The method addFilterBefore(Filter, Class<? extends Filter>) from the type HttpSecurity refers to the missing type Filter"

Both these errors are happening in the addFilterBefore() function. The config file is:

```
package com.armando.pontointeligente.api.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

//import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

//import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.armando.pontointeligente.api.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.armando.pontointeligente.api.security.filters.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig /*extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*/ {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }


    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/api/cadastrar-pj", "/api/cadastrar-pf", "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

}
```

I wanted to create a filter that only accept valid JWT to make the operations.

Link for the repository: https://github.com/Armando-Vidal/ponto-inteligente-api